# Offset of a range in python

Tags: python, limit, offset

I have a csv file with some 1 million records

And I want to partition that csv file into 4 csv files
And give offset of range displaying
Records as
file 1 has  0-250k
file 2 has  251k- 500k
file 3 has  501k- 750k
file 4 has  751k-1000k

How do i do this in python?????

Right now it is displaying it as
file 1 has  0-250k
file 2 has  250k- 500k
file 3 has  500k- 750k
file 4 has  750k-1000k and not incrementing the limit

Lets say we're reading the file with below containing 1 million records

```
def load_f(file):
    return pd.read_csv(file)

print("Loading data..")
file = load_f('F58139.csv')
file= load_f('F58139.csv')
filef = load_f('F58139.csv')
```

for loop --

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
        noOfRcrds = row[0]
        noOfPart=3



limit=math.floor(noOfRcrds /noOfPart)

for i in range(noOfPart):
    offset = i * limit
    sql = sqlTbl.format(tableName=tableName, limit=limit, offset=offset)
    print(sql)
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
    df.to_csv('/tmp/data/{tableName}-{partition}.csv'.format(tableName=tableName,partition=i),index=False,header = False)`
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried? Add some code to your question.

Comment: @Will.Evo Added

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand what you did, but i think you want something like this:

```
def divide_csv(arq, parts):
    with open(arq) as file_in:
        linhas = file_in.readlines()
        n_linhas = len(linhas)
        len_arq = n_linhas // parts
        for i in range(parts):
            offset = i * len_arq
            with open(f'file{i}.csv', 'w') as out:
                for j in range(offset, offset + len_arq): # Just write in correct range
                    out.write(linhas[j])
      

divide_csv('1000_Sales_Records.csv', 4)
```

First, I open the file and store they lines in a list, then I write the lines in new files.

Sorry for my English.